# Label not displayed while using filament group tablesaw plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have been trying to render a responsive table using tablesaw plugin(stack only version) from filament group. View is basically rendered using backbone and underscore templating. However, while reducing the view port the labels are just not getting displayed.

https://github.com/filamentgroup/tablesaw

My back bone view is as below. The model is read from a spec.json file.

```
App.views.AnalyticsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template());
        var $tableBody = this.$el.find('#table-body');
        //Creating analytics table rows from spec.json
        //Appending to table body in analytics page template
        _.each(this.collection.models, function(model) {
            var rowHtml = '<tr>';
            _.each(model.attributes, function(value) {
                rowHtml += '<td>' + value + '</td>';
            });
            rowHtml += '</tr>';
            $tableBody.append(rowHtml);            
        });
        return this;
    }
});
```

My underscore template is as below -

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <p><%_ analytics.intro %></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div>

</div>
    <table class="tablesaw tablesaw-stack" data-tablesaw-mode="stack">
      <thead id="table-head">
         <th><%_ analytics.parameter %></th>
         <th><%_ analytics.title %></th>
         <th><%_ analytics.apisource %></th>
         <th><%_ analytics.description %></th>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="table-body"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The table headers are internationalized using underi18n. I am new to backbone, so please do feel free to let me know if there is a better approach to render the view. My goal is to get a fully responsive table, the data for which will be set from a spec.json file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know it might be difficult but can you share a jsfiddle with the result?

Comment: @AhmadAlfy...getting all of this into jsfiddle is pretty difficult.. However, I now have an idea why the labels are not being rendered... I believe the jQuery plugin is trying to access the page before it has been rendered by backbone ..Am not sure how to call the plugin form the view however

Comment: If you want to make sure your jQuery plugin access the DOM after it has been rendered I always use this `$('#your-selector', this.el).plugin();`

Answer (score 0):

So the problem has been solved. I had to edit a few lines in the tablesaw plugin, specifically where events were triggered.

Earlier it was - `this.$table.trigger( events.create, [ this, colstart ] );`, which was not triggering the required event. I changed it to `$( document ).trigger( events.create, [ this, colstart ] );`, which got it working.

I called the plugin directly using `this.$el.find("#analytics-table").table();` Further I also removed the 'enhance-tablesaw' event associated with the plugin.

thanks @ahmad for your help